# URL rewrite for a clean format

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i am trying to have my urls look like cleaner using the below but its not working i don't know if i should add anything else,

*this is how it looks now*

example.com/product.php?product_id=144&product_name=50ml-bottle-with-glasses,-shirt

*this is how i want them to look*

example.com/product/144/50ml-bottle-with-glasses,-shirt

*basically here's what i used*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    product.php?product_id=$1&product_name=$2   [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Thank you

Comment: Please stop asking the same question again. You asked the same 3 times within 24 hours. Wait for someone to answer it.

Comment: this is different @tomudding and no answered the other one, if you have any knowledge in htaccess try to help instead of just commenting uselessly

Comment: What exactly is not working? And what error does the server return?

Comment: @starkeen the url is not changing its staying as is and i have no errors showing up,

example.com/product.php?product_id=144&product_name=50ml-bottle-with-glasses,-shirt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
#1)redirect from "/product\.php\?product_id=123&product_name=foo" to "/product/123/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?product_id=([^&]+)&product_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product/%1/%2? [NE,L,R]

#2)internally map "/product/123/foo" to "/product\.php\?product_id=123&product_name=foo"
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$    product.php?product_id=$1&product_name=$2   [B,NC,L]
```

Comment: This is because apache was converting special chars to their hex code. I have remove the B flag from the first rule .Try the updated rule.

Comment: the url looks clean now, but the request i not being processed i'm getting 400 Bad request, any clue ? @starkeen

Answer (score 0):

There are comma into your parameter `product_name`. Try to change your .htaccess and add comma into your regular expression for this parameter: `([A-Za-z0-9-,]+)`. So your htaccess will be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-,]+)$    product.php?product_id=$1&product_name=$2   [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: can i remove this comma from the urls using htaccess ?

Comment: nothing happened, should i add anything i read on another thread that i should add 
Options +FollowSymLinks is this related ?

Comment: the ending `/?` in `^product/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-,]+)?/$  `was redundant:) remove it and try again

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still not working, nothing is changing in the url